# Cleanup Codeigniter Applications Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I'm interested in cleaning up my codeigniter applications folder (just to clean up the clutter). I've seen a few applications that only include the important folder (ex. controllers, models, views, config) and do away with alot of the other stuff (like logs, hooks etc.)

Does someone know which folders can be deleted and which are required?

Thanks

Comment: Just sounds like a plain bad idea! Why remove these folders? There really aren't that many as it is and you may need to use them in the future. I really wouldn't go there.

Comment: Your probably right.. Thanks Haraldo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that this "clean up" won't bring you this great advantages, apart from your personal feelings. Since Codeigniter tries to look into application folders which are named like the system ones (libraries, core..) before going to search for those folders inside the "system", I don't think it will be painless to remove them; you might try, though, and just keep those which, very likely, contain somethin: config,controllers,errors,models,views.

Another thing you could do, and which will free more "space" (are you worried about file count?), is deleting unused/unwanted helpers and libraries (from the system folder); the ones you are damn sure you don't use and never will in the future (like the javascript library, for ex, plainly useless, or the smiley helper...You got the point).

All in all, apart from the feeling of "having cleaned up your workspace", I don't really see what benefit this will bring you. But, if you really, really feel so strongly inclined to, make a back-up copy and start deleting, you can always put them back if CI yells at you.

Comment: Thanks Damien.. thanks for the advice. My goal was to make navigating back and forth between the different folders quicker. What i've decided to do instead is mark model, view and controller folder as favorites in netbeans :)

Answer (score 0):

Each file and folder in the CodeIgniter Application folder is an extension of the whole CodeIgniter framework in one form or another, and should not be tampered with. CodeIgniter is a light, fast framework, and should not need any other "modifications". If you'd like to play around with CodeIgniter though to try out any "improvements"; I'd check out their page on [GitHub](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter), view some commits that may be related to your question, and play around with it yourself on your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

The framework is setup so you can develop your applications and update to new versions of code igniter without breaking said applications.  You don't want to start messing with the actual framework that's just asking for random errors.

if you are trying to make it as lite as possible just auto load the libraries and helpers that you require directly into the controller where they are needed.

-L